# How to return a column value in case result is empty in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a SQL query to fetch 3 column values. Sometimes I don't get records. What I need is a query that always returns `field1`, even if `field2` and `field3` are NULL.

**I'm using `field1` as input:**

```
AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
```

How can I always return these values?

**Complete SQL query:**

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    name1.field1,
                    name1.field2,
                    name3.field3,
                    name4.field4,
                    @pl2 := IF( @pl1 = name1.field1, @pl2, 1) as pl2,
                    @pl1 := name1.field1
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            @pl1 := NULL,
                            @pl2 := 0
                    )
                    R,
                    db1.field5 AS name1,
                    db1.field6 AS name2,
                    db1.field7 AS name3,
                    db1.field8 AS name4
                WHERE
                    name2.field9 = name1.field9
                    AND name3.field10 = name2.field10
                    AND name4.field11 = name3.field3
                    AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
                    AND field12 LIKE 'helloworld'
                    AND name2.field13 LIKE 'helloworld'
                GROUP BY name1.field1
                ORDER BY name1.field14 desc
            )
            A
        WHERE
            pl2 = 1
```

**Current output (wrong):**

```
AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2', 'test3')

field1 | field2 | field3
test3  | hello  | world

AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2')

field1 | field2 | field3
```

**Needed output:**

```
AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2', 'test3')

field1 | field2 | field3
test1  | [this part doesn't matter]
test2  | [this part doesn't matter]
test3  | hello  | world

AND field1 IN('test1', 'test2')

field1 | field2 | field3
test1  | [this part doesn't matter]
test2  | [this part doesn't matter]
```

Comment: You are not clear. Please give example input including a table and desired output, and tryto clearly explain how the output is determined by the input.

Comment: @philipxy I've added output...

Comment: Write the query with JOIN sintax and use LEFT JOIN with table db1.field7.

Comment: @etsa Could you please describe it a little more? As an answer maybe...?

Comment: Give me some time: I could do it faster if you should post sample CREATE TABLE and INSERT scripts

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to those... :(

Comment: You can create them by hand... this should be a small "effort" that one should pay to ask help to others...

Comment: @etsa I will try to do that, but my tables have over 40 columns, so I think it will take a long time...

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `UNION ALL` work?

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve]s. (Note that means *don't* give 40 columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a said in comment, I couldn't test as there are not (partial) script to CREATE TABLE and sample data insert.
I thought something like that: can you see if it works for you?

```
SELECT NAME1.FIELD1
, NAME1.FIELD2
, NAME3.FIELD3
, NAME4.FIELD4
, @pl2 := IF( @pl1 = NAME1.FIELD1, @pl2, 1) AS pl2
, @pl1 := NAME1.FIELD1
FROM FIELD5 AS NAME1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @pl1 := NULL, @pl2 := 0) R
INNER JOIN DB1.FIELD6 AS NAME2 ON NAME1.FIELD9 = NAME2.FIELD9
LEFT JOIN DB1.FIELD7 AS NAME3 ON NAME3.FIELD10 = NAME2.FIELD10
LEFT JOIN DB1.FIELD8 AS NAME4 ON NAME4.FIELD11 = NAME3.FIELD3
WHERE FIELD1 IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
AND name2.field13 LIKE 'helloworld'
GROUP BY NAME1.FIELD1
ORDER BY NAME1.FIELD14 DESC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you say `SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2, field3)` instead

Comment: Tried this but gives me only field3 for test3 as output. I still need field3 for test1 and test2